# Crystal Reports Changing the Data Source

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, ole, database

I have a Crystal report where the data source has originally been set to use ODBC connections.  Now I want to modify the data source to instead use OLE DB instead of using ODBC.  How do I replace the data source connection without breaking the database fields which I have originally set up for my report?  If I try to delete the original data source, the fields which I have already set up are also deleted.  Is there a way to map the report to use OLE DB instead of the ODBC connection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Its easy. Right click on the database fields in your field explorer. Click on 'Set datasource location' And then you will see two sections in a dialog.  "Current datasource" and "replace with". In the current datasource - select the object you want to replace. Then in the "Replace with" section click on "create new connection">"OLE DB">Connect to the database object that you want by supplying driver and credential information.

Then click the 'update' button on the right side. That's it! You're done. Though the object name might not seem to change in the 'current datasource' section, still if u click on the (+) sign next to the object, the source name will show the new OLEDB object that you used

Comment: Yes easy for 1 report maybe what about 200? How can this procedure be scripted?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Adding the OLE DB data source to the
   report **without** deleting the ODBC
   data source.
2. Use the Set Datasource
   Location option (from the Database
   menu in the Report Designer) to
   change the datasource for the table
   from the ODBC data source to the OLE
   DB data source.
3. **Then** delete the ODBC data source from the report.

Answer (score -2):

Crystal Report 8.5

Click 'Database' menu->Click 'Remove From Report'->Select the tables which you want to remove from the list->click 'Remove' option->Click 'Done'Button.

That's it:)

Comment: The question wasn't about removing the data source; it was about *replacing* the data source. And the question already has an accepted answer for this, posted 6 years ago.

Comment: removing the datasource also auto removes any fields from your report linked to that datasource. Then you are really messed up with a non running report.