# Crystal Reports - Change report name displayed when changing the data source

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I have a report in Crystal 2013, and I changed the data source from one procedure to another in the same Oracle database.  That works, but the procedure name showing is still the old name.  If I drill down, it shows the correct procedure name (as described in the 2nd paragraph of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803209/crystal-reports-changing-the-data-source)).

However, because of how this is maintained, having that old name can cause confusion in maintaining this report.  Is there a way to change the name displayed for the report so it matches the properties?

```
- report
  - DatabaseName
      + Properties
      - Old Report Name   <-- I want to change this
          - Properties
              Table Name: New Report Name
              Table Type: Stored Procedures
              Owner: DatabaseOwner
              Overridden Qualified Table Name:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the area where the procedure is used, either the main report or a sub-report, go to Database, Database Expert.  Where the Selected Tables are listed, right-click and choose Rename.*  This fixes the report name where ever it is displayed, including in formulas and the field explorer.

*F2 was mentioned in the other answer, and will work at the point of selecting the procedure name.  Essentially it will work instead of the right-click.  At any point before that, nothing happens with F2.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default crystal report map the variable with db field, so if you change procedure and if new column create, then report will add, if you remove, it will remove.

The same thing with procedures name, because designing of all fields in report is map with procedure's name and its fields, I don't remember, but either you can rename procedure by f2 or no option to change due to internal use.

You can change/add/remove the field name by updating datasource.

Comment: The column names are all the same between the two procedures.  And I'm not asking about field names, but about the procedure name itself.

Comment: F2 doesn't seem to do anything.  So maybe it's the second option: no option to change.

Comment: good that you solved it. I already mention that procedure's name rename is something tedious a.