# Not able to bind crystal report properly when using dataset, showing parameters missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, xsd, crystal-reports, dataset

I have crystal report which is working fine when I use `DSN` as a datasource. 
Problem is I am using dataset now. Dataset contains all the table I need and I am populating it with data from database using Stored procedure. 
But, in this way, it is throwing an error : "`Missing Parameters`".

I am doing as below :
**Step 1** : Creating `Dataset1.xsd` and using `data connections` inserting all required `tables` from database in it.
**Step 2** :Giving `data source` to report using `database expert` as `Dataset1.xsd`
**Step 3** : Populating data using Stored procedure in data set and then creating instance of `Dataset1` and merging data from data set to `Dataset 1` instance.

My code to fetch data from database and then merge that to `Dataset1` instance and giving that as source to crystal report is as below :

```
Private Sub ReportByDataset(ByVal rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument)

    'new code

    Dim myConnection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()
    'myConnection.ConnectionString = "server= (local)\NetSDK;database=pubs;Trusted_Connection=yes"
    Dim ds As New DataSet1

    myConnection.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HighriseContractingWebConnectionString").ConnectionString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim MyCommand As New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    MyCommand.Connection = myConnection

    MyCommand.CommandText = "SP_Web_GetReportTables"
    MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Dim MyDA As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    MyDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
    Dim myDS As New DataSet

    MyDA.Fill(myDS)
    myConnection.Close()


    ds.Tables("RABill_RPT").Merge(myDS.Tables(0), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    myDS.Tables(0).Reset()
    ds.Tables("RA_bills").Merge(myDS.Tables(1), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Work_Completion").Merge(myDS.Tables(2), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("contractor").Merge(myDS.Tables(3), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("WO_Header").Merge(myDS.Tables(4), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Project").Merge(myDS.Tables(5), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("contractor_1").Merge(myDS.Tables(6), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Users").Merge(myDS.Tables(7), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Users_Approved").Merge(myDS.Tables(8), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("voucher").Merge(myDS.Tables(9), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Employee_Approve").Merge(myDS.Tables(10), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Employee").Merge(myDS.Tables(11), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Account").Merge(myDS.Tables(12), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("TDS").Merge(myDS.Tables(13), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("WO_Detail").Merge(myDS.Tables(14), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("V_WO_BlockTaskNo").Merge(myDS.Tables(15), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("TASK").Merge(myDS.Tables(16), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Cont_Voucher").Merge(myDS.Tables(17), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Cont_Voucher_1").Merge(myDS.Tables(17), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Cont_Voucher_2").Merge(myDS.Tables(17), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)
    ds.Tables("Company").Merge(myDS.Tables(18), MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)


    ''new code ends


    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
    CRReport.HasCrystalLogo = False
    CRReport.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = False
    CRReport.ReportSource = rptDoc
    CRReport.DataBind()

End Sub
```

But it is not working, what am I missing. Same works fine using `DSN`  It is not problem of parameters and same is working fine other way.
**Note: I know above code is not memory optimised, but my concern for now is to somehow make it work, I can later optimise it**

Below image shows Dataset1 as datasource
[image]

Comment: is this quetion our home task?

Comment: It is not home task!!! What is making you think so. I just need to make my crystal report work in Non-DNS way due to environmental issues at client side.

Comment: Change the Datasource from ODBC to XML/Datasource             
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803209/crystal-reports-changing-the-data-source

Comment: Datasource for report is set to dataset1

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities - where are you getting the parameters missing error thrown?  If it is on the stored procedure SP_Web_GetReportTables, you are not adding any parameters for that sproc on MyCommand.  If it is on the report itself, check under the Field Explorer on the side of the report itself and see if you have any parameters defined there, that were left over from using the DSN.  Since you are now passing in a dataset directly, you don't need to pass any parameters in. Finally, if this is using the Crystal Report Viewer, just setting the ReportSource should display it, I am not sure what the DataBind is doing for you.

Comment: correct; when the datasource is ado.net, report parameters are redundant and have to be removed.

Answer (score -1):

If you create a new data source and delete the old one, CR will delete your parameters related to query parameters for that data source as well. It's better to change data source.

Comment: in my experience it does not delete them. for me the process was:  
1) do "find in formulas" for each parameter and delete the usage. 2) after that the green flag should be gone. if its not, change the parameter to another type, do a check database. 3) right click delete parameter